# Sum up digits in column to get one number

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I write a SQL statement (SQL Server) which will be able to create column B which will contain sum  of digits in column A. For example:

Column A value = 12345
Column B value = 1+2+3+4+5 = 15

I might try function Left couple of times and then separate every digit in the separate column and then sum those columns.

K, folks
thank U for your effort of giving advise:
I figured that statement out which works for me perfectly cause values in the column I have to sum digits will never exceed more than 10 of them. For my computed column is all i need to achieve that sum goal.
I worked a lot with an excel and might not see things as SQL programmers, for me this code works.

```
SELECT '1234567'
    , convert(integer,left('1234567',1))
    + convert(integer,right(left('1234567',2),1))
    + convert(integer,right(left('1234567',iif(len('1234567') >= 3, 3, 0)),1))
    + convert(integer,right(left('1234567',iif(len('1234567') >= 4, 4, 0)),1))
    + convert(integer,right(left('1234567',iif(len('1234567') >= 5, 5, 0)),1)) 
    + convert(integer,right(left('1234567',iif(len('1234567') >= 6, 6, 0)),1))
    + convert(integer,right(left('1234567',iif(len('1234567') >= 7, 7, 0)),1))
    + convert(integer,right(left('1234567',iif(len('1234567') >= 8, 8, 0)),1))
    + convert(integer,right(left('1234567',iif(len('1234567') >= 9, 9, 0)),1))
    + convert(integer,right(left('1234567',iif(len('1234567') >= 10, 10, 0)),1))
```

Comment: What datatyoe is column A?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL #1**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, digits VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @tbl (digits) VALUES
('12345'),
('1234567890');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT id, digits, result = SUM(TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(digits, number, 1) AS INT))
FROM @tbl CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT DISTINCT number
    FROM master..spt_values
    WHERE number BETWEEN 1 and LEN(digits)
) V
GROUP BY id, digits;
```

**SQL #2**

```
-- SQL Server 2022 onwards
SELECT id, digits, result = SUM(TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(digits, value, 1) AS INT))
FROM @tbl 
    CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(1, LEN(digits))
GROUP BY id, digits;
```

**Output**

| id | digits | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | 15 |
| 2 | 1234567890 | 45 |

Comment: Hi,
I worked a lot with an excel and might not see things as SQL programmers, for me this code worked, cause I dunno need more than check up to 10 digits:

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation in addition to working code.

Comment: @DanielMoniak, glad to hear that the proposed solution(s) is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as answered. Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

This is not really SQL Server's forte, but you could do something like this:

```sql
declare @data table (i bigint)

insert into @data 
values  (12345)
,   (100000000009)
,   (3333)

;with cte as (
    select cast(row_number() over(order by @@spid) as int) AS sort
    from (
    values (1), (2), (3), (4),(5)
    ) x(x)
    cross apply (
        values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(30)
        ) y(y)
    )
select *
from @data d
cross apply (
    select sum(num) as total
    from (
        select cast(substring(cast(d.i as nvarchar(30)), c.sort, 1) as int) as num
        from cte c
        where c.sort <= LEN(d.i)
        ) x
    ) y
```

I create a little series table in a CTE between 1 and 30, and then one substring each character from the number and summarize them in an APPLY.

In newer versions you can use GENERATE_SERIES to skip the CTE.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table mydata (N bigint);

insert into mydata
(N)
values  
(12345),
(999999),
(123456789);
```

use following query

```
SELECT a.N
    ,sum(cast(substring(a.b, v.number + 1, 1) AS INT)) Result
FROM (
    SELECT N
        ,cast(N AS NVARCHAR(max)) b
    FROM mydata
    ) a
INNER JOIN master..spt_values v ON v.number < len(a.b)
WHERE v.type = 'P'
GROUP BY a.N
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TMBYdHyX)

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation in addition to working code